# on click function fades out and fades. This function shows img on top of another img, but never matches screen size

Tags: javascript, css, button, onclick, click

Image doesn't appear on top of another image exactly, because of different screens. It appears that I need a new function. One that doesn't go on top of another image (by funcion on click for a a few secs), but rather replace for those few secs.

I have tried to use %, vw, vh, px . To match pictures exactly. 
Here is a codepen:
https://codepen.io/karolis-rusevicius/pen/KbEqqE

```
<html lang="en">
```

I expect the image to be replaced during button click function or the image is exactly on top of the static image on any screen size

Comment: you are missing the ending `"` on the `src` attribute of the `img` tag. Just one thing I saw. Also why are you using `img src=""` when you have background-url and background styles applied to it? just make it a div with the same style as the other one.

Comment: Thanks, I have updated the code. I am also looking at this thread for answers: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46374335/change-image-onclick-for-a-set-amount-of-time/46374376

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to make sure your pictures are cropped at the same size, then assure that the width and height of each photo are the same set static value, such as:

`200px`